# Como saber os arquivos e pastas que não estão sendo usados?

Tags: template

Tenho um template para web, e nele tem vários arquivos de imagens, css e js. Minha dúvida é se tem como eu saber quais arquivos não estão sendo utilizados sem eu ter que abrir cada html, css e js para saber o que tem relação ou não.